# Replaced Water Filter in Refrigerator, Now Having Issues (Loud Noise, Increase Water Flow)

Tags: refrigerator, water-filtration

I have a Whirlpool refrigerator that has a built in ice and water dispenser, I can't remember the model number but I don't think it should matter for the issue I am having.  I recently replaced the water filter, the old one was working fine but it had reached the end of the life of the filter.  When I replaced it, a simple open the filter door, unscrew the old one, screw in the new one (made sure it was installed properly), closed the filter door.

I ran 3 gallons of water through it as instructed but the whole time there was a much louder noise when the water was running, almost like a machine gun going off (not that loud obviously but that type of noise).  My refrigerator also has a measured fill option where you can dispense one cup (or more) and it cuts off automatically. Along with the loud noise when I have it dispense one cup it dispenses significantly more, around twice as much as with the previous filter.

The water is not really cloudy after running the three gallons through it but it seems to me that perhaps the issue is it isn't sealing properly and air is getting in the line, hence the loud noise?  I pulled the filter out and it seems like the O-rings are in place like they should be and I can't determine an issue from visual inspection.  Since it occurred after replacing the filter I can't imagine it is an issue anywhere else in the system.

Any ideas? Did I just get a defective filter?

Comment: Try the old filter back in the system. Soak the new filter in some fresh water. Did you move the refrigerator? Where is the sound coming from - the piping, the water line, the inside of the fridge, the filter area, or the dispenser?

Comment: Unfortunately I threw the old one in the trash so I can't put it back in. I did not move the fridge though, the filter is accessible from the inside of the fridge so all you have to do is open the door and it's right there.  I will try soaking it in some water, that's a good thought, thanks.

Comment: I know that filters are not cheap, however you could buy another one, soak it and install it. See if that make a difference.